# When consolidating duplicate literals, will a C compiler look in the middle of a string?

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

I have a lot of literal strings in my source code that are otherwise identical except for leading white-spaces (due to a desire to maintain correct indentation). Are compilers smart enough to see that it can reuse the space in memory for both, just offsetting one string by a couple bytes?

Comment: You mean, literals with common suffix?

Comment: @Dvorak. Yes, if by that you mean one string is a suffix of another. Ex. "abc" and "___abc".

Comment: All the literals are in the same .c file if that makes any difference.

Comment: Note that the final \0 is part of the literal string. That is, there is an opportunity to factor "banana" and "nana", but not "banana" and "bana". There is also an opportunity to factor "banana" and "banana\000apple", or for that matter "nana" and "banana\000apple". I had fun trying to enumerate the cases in which a static analyzer should warn (that is the cases when the results of `==` depend on compilation): http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/06/04/Valid-compare-pointers

Comment: According to my tests, neither GCC nor Clang perform this optimization, even with `-fmerge-all-constants` and `-Os`.

Comment: Is there a way to refactor your code so that rather than repeating the string literal all the time you reference the same static `char[]` at different offsets? That would more-or-less guarantee the optimisation you are after.

Comment: I guess I'll just remove all the extra spaces with a regexp before delivery. The indentation is nice to have for debugging purpose. It's not critical.

Comment: @cleong Don't, my compact answer generated 8 downvotes, I don't want to have been hurt for nuttin' :-) !

Answer (score 1):

ISO c99 6.5.2.5 Compound literals

83) This allows implementations to share storage for string literals and constant compound literals with the same or overlapping representations.

Comment: Huh?? Compound literals have nothing to do with string literals. Furthermore, foot notes are not normative text in ISO standards.

Comment: really `"foot notes are not normative text in ISO standards"`.... i donno actully i found this a little meaningful so i just answered.. thanks for info .. anyway it says about both compound and string literals

Comment: @Lundin : I thought of short and concise answer

Comment: The normative text connected to that foot note says "String literals, and compound literals with const-qualified types, need not designate distinct objects." In other words, it says that if you use a compound literal (aka "anonymous variable") and make it constant, the compiler is free to optimize them to the same memory location. However, this refers to string literals _inside_ compound literals, for example:  `char[]{"foo"}`. Though out of coincidence, the same applies to string literals anywhere. No matter, this has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: probably.

Long answer: it depends on the implementation. Typically, C compilers have an optimizer feature called "string pool" or similar, which enables the compiler to store all string literals adjacently in ROM.

The contents of that string pool may then be optimized, the very same string appearing twice will almost certainly get optimized out. I think that most compilers will also be smart enough to recognize sub strings. But there are also platform considerations such as alignment, so just because there exists a sub string, it doesn't necessarily mean that it will be most effective to re-use that memory location.

There is nothing in the C standard that *guarantees* that such optimizations are done. But at the same time, there is nothing in the standard preventing it either.

To be sure, you have to check your specific compiler's documentation, or disassemble your program, or check the linker output.

Answer (score -4):

Simple answer: No. I do not know of any compiler doing this.

Comment: You should comment that, because it's not a real answer

Comment: Well, the question was if there are any compilers that do this kind of string pooling. There isn´t, that´s a fact, as far as I know. They could do it, but they don´t. So what else should one comment on this? That it would not be worth the effort?

Comment: Hey! I want a badge for 8 downvotes! And: Why the upvotes? :)

Comment: There's only 4 downvotes on your answer. You lose 2 reputation points per downvote.